# Validate whether grouped radio boxes are checked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to check wether at least one radio button per group has been checked an would appreciate some help for my particular case very much.

```
<tr>
 <td> Group1 </td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl1" name="wahl1" value="1"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl1" name="wahl1" value="2"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl1" name="wahl1" value="3"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl1" name="wahl1" value="4"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl1" name="wahl1" value="5"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl1" name="wahl1" value="6"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl1" name="wahl1" value="7"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
 <td> Group2 </td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl2" name="wahl2" value="1"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl2" name="wahl2" value="2"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl2" name="wahl2" value="3"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl2" name="wahl2" value="4"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl2" name="wahl2" value="5"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl2" name="wahl2" value="6"></td>
     <td><input type="radio" id="wahl2" name="wahl2" value="7"></td>
   </tr>
<tr>
```

I was trying to solve this with a pure javascipt function which for my purposes has to be defined inside a button like this:

```
<input name="submFragebogen2" type="submit" id="fragebogen2"  value="Absenden" style="display: none">

<input type="button" value="Absenden" onclick="
    function test2() {

        var radios  = document.getElementsByName("input");
        var counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (radios[i].checked) {
                counter = counter +  1;
            }
        }     
        if (counter != 2) {
            alert('Please choose an option in each row.');
        } else {
            var subButton2 = document.getElementsByName('submFragebogen2')[0];
            subButton2.style.display='inline';
            subButton2.click();
            subButton2.style.display='none'
        }
    };
    test2();"
```

> 

Comment: it does not NEED to be defined inside the button, just define it in your code and do `onclick="test2()"`

Comment: @juvian, thx for your comment. The problem is, that the web framework I'm using doesn't allow this. So I really need to do a work around like this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this using JQuery with the following code:

```
$("[name=wahl1]:checked").length > 0
```

The selector will select only inputs with name "wahl1" that has been checked. Then you just see if there are more than one of them.

If you are looking for a pure JavaScript code try this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByName("wahl2"), checked = false;
for(var i=0; i<elements.length-1; i++){ 
    checked = checked || elements[i].checked; 
}
if(!checked){ 
    alert("Please select at least one."); 
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z6eud4kx/

Comment: thx for this suggestion. I tried the pure JavaScript code but it seems not to work in my "in button" definition. Do you perhaps know if this approach, in principle, works?

Comment: That works great, and especially in my "in button" definition, so just what I'm looking for, thx a lot, I appreciate for this quick help!

Answer (score 1):

use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get only radio button.

`document.getElementsByName("input")` will return all type of input.

e.g. button,textfield,hidden field.etc.

```
function test2() {

        var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]")
        var counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = radios.length; i < len; i++) {
            ...
        }
        if (counter != 2) {
            alert('Please choose an option in each row.');
        } else {
            ..
        }
    };
```

HTML :

```
<input type="button" value="Absenden" onclick="test2()"/>
```

Comment: also thx a lot for your comments. As in my comment in the answer above, I still struggle to get such work in my "in button" definition of the function. Unfortunately, I'm restricted to such. Perhaps you got any idea?

Answer (score 0):

some errors in the html code. The id should be unique. remove the same id of the inputs.

with pure javascript you need this code:

```
function checkRadios() {
  var wahl1RadiosChecked = false;
  var wahl2RadiosChecked = false;

  var wahl1Radios = document.getElementsByName('wahl1');
  var wahl2Radios = document.getElementsByName('wahl2');


  for( i = 0; i < wahl1Radios.length; i++ ) {
    if( wahl1Radios[i].checked ) {
      wahl1RadiosChecked = true;
    }
  }

  for( i = 0; i < wahl2Radios.length; i++ ) {
    if( wahl2Radios[i].checked ) {
      wahl2RadiosChecked = true;
    }
  }

  if (wahl1RadiosChecked === false || wahl2RadiosChecked === false) {
    alert('Please choose an option in each row.');
  } else {
    var subButton2 = document.getElementsByName('submFragebogen2')[0];
    subButton2.style.display='inline';
    subButton2.click();
    subButton2.style.display='none';
  }
}
```

Inside the button you need to call this function.

Here is the example: https://jsbin.com/wujuwimide/edit?html,js,console,output

Of course with jquery you avoid having so much code.